# Jquery Determine which button by keyup

Tags: jquery

Hi have some buttons labeled A-G. The id's on the buttons are as follows.

```
"btn_A"
"btn_B"
"btn_C"
etc...
```

I am running a keyup function as follows.

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
     var theButton =  "btn_"+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
     alert(theButton)
});
```

That gets me the correct buttons "id", but how can I then do something wit the button. Like get the `text()` from it or `hide()` it etc.

The buttons are defined as follows:

```
<button id="btn_A">A</button>
<button id="btn_B">B</button>
<button id="btn_C">C</button>
```

What I am trying to do is when someone presses the correct key on the keyboard the corresponding button would hide(). For example if they pressed "A" the the A button would hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop either of these at the end of your function:

```
$('#'+theButton).text();
$('#'+theButton).hide();
```

The $('#'+element_id_here) jQuery selector is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the element through the event object.

```
alert($(event.target).text());
```

Also, what you are actually doing is event delegation, so something like this will work (in jquery 1.7)

```
$(document).on("keyup","[id^=btn]",function(){
  var theButton =  "btn_"+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  alert(theButton);
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Hi. This seems to not fire at all. I am not getting any alerts. Using latest jQuery.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/e7vPy/ maybe your error is elsewhere. You didn't show us your DOM.

Comment: I updated my quesstion to try and make it more clear. The jsfiddle seems not to work in Firefox, works in chrome however.